# Spring SAML - how to add custom fields on the SP HTTP request?

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

My service provider uses HTTP-Post binding to send the request to the IDP. I need to add new fields to the form. Right now I'm sending the "SAMLRequest" and "RelayState", but I also need to send "option" and "profile", these are fields required by our IDP. How can I accomplish this with Spring Saml security?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include additional fields in the `Extensions` element of the SAML `AuthnRequest` message. In order to so you need to overriding class `WebSSOProfileImpl` and configure your new implementation class in the `securityContext.xml`. The `Extensions` element can be constructed for example like this:

```
package example;

import org.opensaml.common.SAMLException;
import org.opensaml.saml2.common.Extensions;
import org.opensaml.saml2.common.impl.ExtensionsBuilder;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.AuthnRequest;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.AssertionConsumerService;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.SingleSignOnService;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException;
import org.opensaml.xml.schema.XSAny;
import org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLMessageContext;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions;

/**
 * Customization of the AuthnRequest generation.
 */
public class WebSSOProfile extends WebSSOProfileImpl {

    public WebSSOProfile() {
    }

    public WebSSOProfile(SAMLProcessor processor, MetadataManager manager) {
        super(processor, manager);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthnRequest getAuthnRequest(SAMLMessageContext context, WebSSOProfileOptions options, AssertionConsumerService assertionConsumer, SingleSignOnService bindingService) throws SAMLException, MetadataProviderException {
        AuthnRequest authnRequest = super.getAuthnRequest(context, options, assertionConsumer, bindingService);
        authnRequest.setExtensions(buildExtensions());
        return authnRequest;
    }

    protected Extensions buildExtensions() {

        XSAny extraElement = new XSAnyBuilder().buildObject("urn:myexample:extraAttribute", "ExtraElement", "myexample");
        extraElement.setTextContent("extraValue");

        Extensions extensions = new ExtensionsBuilder().buildObject();
        extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(extraElement);

        return extensions;

    }

}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this within a Grails application? I need to override the WebSSOProfileImpl.buildReturnAddress method.